# Magento 2 : Products Listing Page URL

Tags: magento2, product, category

I have created a block of menu for my navigation:

```
<ul>
    <li class="ui-menu-item level0">
        <a href="{{store url=""}}" class="level-top"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item level0">
        <a href="{{store url=""}}" class="level-top"><span>Products</span></a>
    </li>              
</ul>
```

If you can see there is link I have added for products page but I'm unsure what URL should I give in `href="{{store url=""}}"`

I have just default category and just wanted to display products on front end by clicking on products!

Comment: For your requirement, you need to do one things, create one category and added product into that category and put that category URL here.

Comment: We cannot use Root category right?

Comment: yes, can not use Root Category.